# pandas dataframe style format rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to format some of the rows in my dataframe. On this [pandas page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) they show the example below of using a dictionary to format specific columns, is it possible to do this with rows instead?

```
Use a dictionary to format specific columns.

df.style.format({'B': "{:0<4.0f}", 'D': '{:+.2f}'})
```

Answer (score 0):

New in version 0.17.1

Provisional styling

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/style.html

so it is coming soon